# ext.js site won't render when adding grid "requires"

Tags: javascript, extjs

js and I got a strange issue when adding a perfectly normal 'Ext.grid.Panel' to list of requires:

```
Ext.define('AcWeb.view.WestView', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    requires: [
        'Ext.layout.container.Accordion',
        'Ext.grid.Panel'
    ],

    xtype: 'west-view',
    layout: 'accordion',
    title: '',
    // width: 250,
    // minWidth: 250,
    // maxWidth: 250,
    // minHeight: 400,
    defaults: {
        bodyPadding: 10
    },

...
```

Thing is whenever I comment out the  'Ext.grid.Panel' line, the page renders well...
There seems to be no way of getting the reason to the error (nothing in browser console nor in the build log - I issue a "sencha app build" before testing the site)

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for that behavior so something is seriously broken. I would think about re-downloading, re-installing Ext. You can also "Pause to uncaught exceptions" but if you don't get any errors in console it wouldn't stop the code anyway.

As the last resort, I'd re-create workspace/app and I'd start to copy files one by one to the newly generated structure.

Also, check model convert functions, templates, overrides around the culprit grid.